# Writing data on separate rows in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract news headlines from Hindustantimes.com. I have the following code but i get the data in different columns in the same row. I want each news on separate line. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import bs4
import csv
res=requests.get('https://www.hindustantimes.com')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

x=[]
for i in soup.select('div.subhead4'):
    x.append(i.text)

for i in soup.select('div.bigstory-mid-h3'):
    x.append(i.text)

for i in x:
    print(i)

with open('newz.csv','w') as cF:
    wr = csv.writer(cF)
    wr.writerow(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`writerow` takes an iterable to write:

```
writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
-> a,b,c
```

Also, you don't need to append the data to a list before you write.

```
stories = soup.select('div.subhead4') + soup.select('div.bigstory-mid-h3')

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for headline in stories:
        writer.writerow([headline.text.strip()])
```

Comment: This makes more sense than doing the other code. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

```
res = requests.get('https://www.hindustantimes.com')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

x=[]
for i in soup.select('div.subhead4'):
    x.append(i.text.strip())

for i in soup.select('div.bigstory-mid-h3'):
    x.append(i.text.strip())


with open('newz.csv','w') as cF:
    wr = csv.writer(cF)
    for i in x:
        wr.writerow([i])
```

Answer (score 0):

it simple .csv file, here without using csv module

```
with open('newz.csv','w') as cF:
  for x in soup.select('.subhead4 a'):
    cF.write(x.text + '\n')
```